# How to update an object or bail if it has been deleted in Django

Tags: python, django, locking, celery, database-locking

I have a Django app saving objects to the database and a celery task that periodically does some processing on some of those objects.  The problem is that the user can delete an object *after* it has been selected by the celery task for processing, but *before* the celery task has actually finished processing and saving it.  So when the celery task does call `.save()`, the object re-appears in the database even though the user deleted it.  Which is really spooky for users, of course.

So here's some code showing the problem:

```
def my_delete_view(request, pk):
    thing = Thing.objects.get(pk=pk)
    thing.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('yay')

@app.task
def my_periodic_task():
    things = get_things_for_processing()
    # if the delete happens anywhere between here and the .save(), we're hosed
    for thing in things:
        process_thing(thing) # could take a LONG time
        thing.save()
```

I thought about trying to fix it by adding an atomic block and a transaction to test if the object actually exists before saving it:

```
@app.task
def my_periodic_task():
    things = Thing.objects.filter(...some criteria...)
    for thing in things:
        process_thing(thing) # could take a LONG time
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                # just see if it still exists:
                unused = Thing.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=thing.pk)
                # no exception means it exists. go ahead and save the
                # processed version that has all of our updates.
                thing.save()
         except Thing.DoesNotExist:
             logger.warning("Processed thing vanished")
```

Is this the correct pattern to do this sort of thing?  I mean, I'll find out if it works within a few days of running it in production, but it would be nice to know if there are any other well-accepted patterns for accomplishing this sort of thing.

What I really want is to be able to update an object *if it still exists in the database*.  I'm ok with the race between user edits and edits from the `process_thing`, and I can always throw in a `refresh_from_db` just before the `process_thing` to minimize the time during which user edits would be lost.  But I definitely can't have objects re-appearing after the user has deleted them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, it seems like the pattern of "select again atomically, then save" is sufficient:

```
@app.task
def my_periodic_task():
    things = Thing.objects.filter(...some criteria...)
    for thing in things:
        process_thing(thing) # could take a LONG time
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                # just see if it still exists:
                unused = Thing.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=thing.pk)
                # no exception means it exists. go ahead and save the
                # processed version that has all of our updates.
                thing.save()
         except Thing.DoesNotExist:
             logger.warning("Processed thing vanished")
```

(this is the same code as in my original question).

Answer (score 0):

if you open a transaction for the time of processing of celery task, you should avoid such a problems:

```
@app.task
@transaction.atomic
def my_periodic_task():
    things = get_things_for_processing()
    # if the delete happens anywhere between here and the .save(), we're hosed
    for thing in things:
        process_thing(thing) # could take a LONG time
        thing.save()
```

sometimes, you would like to report to the frontend, that you are working on the data, so you can add `select_for_update()` to your queryset (most probably in get_things_for_processing), then in the code responsible for deletion you need to handle errors when db will report that specific record is locked.

Comment: Hmm, I'd rather leave it locked for the shortest amount of time possible (as shown in my question).  Is there any advantage to leaving it locked the whole time over the approach I proposed?

Comment: yes - if you are using data that is stored within this record and you *must* be sure that from the moment you start processing till end - nothing and nobody will change this record

Comment: But that's not what I need :). As stated in the question, I'm ok with the race between user edits and edits from the `process_thing`. I just don't want a deleted object re-appearing.  That's the only thing I'm trying to protect against.